# Cannot properly create rollover on dynamically created html element

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, eval

I created some buttons dynamically based on loop over an array of names, then I want to add rollover actions on these buttons, but the `alert()` in this code always prints the name of the **last** item (**black**).

I tried using `eval()` on that `alert()` part but it didn't make any difference.
I expect it to return *red, green or black* depending on which button I hover the mouse.

```
<div id="channels_buttons_container">
</div>

<script>

channels_array = ["red", "green", "black"];

for(var i = 0; i < channels_array.length; i++) {

    loop_channel_name = channels_array[i];

    // append an element inside the container
    var new_button_element = document.createElement("span");
    new_button_element.id = 'channel_button_'+loop_channel_name;
    new_button_element.innerHTML = '<br>BLA BLA';

    document.getElementById('channels_buttons_container').appendChild(new_button_element);

    // try to add rollover actions on the new button
    document.getElementById('channel_button_'+loop_channel_name).onmouseover = function(){
        alert('Rollover '+loop_channel_name);
    }

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code it's ok but when you use "loop_channel_name" take the last element of array. You must pass the actual element (this):

```
 document.getElementById('channel_button_'+loop_channel_name).onmouseover = function(){

        alert('Rollover '+this.id);
    }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cbertelegni/48q9b/)

Comment: ok, that helped. I set channel_name variable inside the html element like this `new_button_element.channel_name = loop_channel_name;` then referred to it by `new_button_element.onmouseover = function(){alert(this.channel_name)}`; Does that comply with standards ? Setting variable inside html element like that ?

Comment: Yes, in html5 is valid to add attributes to dom nodes. new_button_element["data-color"] = loop_channel_name; see the example: http://jsfiddle.net/48q9b/1/

Answer (score 0):

`loop_channel_name` is initialized as a global variable because you didn't use the `var` keyword. Try `var loop_channel_name` instead of just `loop_channel_name`. When you initialize `loop_channel_name` on the first iteration of the for loop you are creating it as a global variable and on subsequent iterations you are just updating that instead of creating a new reference. By referring to `loop_channel_name` in the alert you are referencing the global variable which was updated to `black` on the last iteration of the loop, hence it always alerting `black`.

**Example**

```
<div id="channels_buttons_container">
</div>

<script>

channels_array = ["red", "green", "black"];

for(var i = 0; i < channels_array.length; i++) {

    var loop_channel_name = channels_array[i];

    var new_button_element = document.createElement("span");
    new_button_element.id = 'channel_button_'+loop_channel_name;
    new_button_element.innerHTML = '<br>BLA BLA';

    document.getElementById('channels_buttons_container').appendChild(new_button_element);

    document.getElementById('channel_button_'+loop_channel_name).onmouseover = function(){
        alert('Rollover '+loop_channel_name);
        /*You could also do*/
        alert('Rollover '+ channels_array[i]);
    }
    // 

}

</script>
```

Comment: It returns the same result (the last instance of loop_channel_name) and the second method (referring to array key directly) it returns `undefined` each time. But I was able to fix this by the method mentioned by @cbertelegni above, I posted a comment. I still don't fully understand why my original code didn't work.